# Boolean Algebra - Tautology for (D or Not D or (anything))

Tags: logic

Ok so I am working on boolean algebra right now and I've stumbled upon my own lemma here, and want to verify that my thinking is correct.

If you have something that end up being in the form:

```
(D OR (NOT D) OR [ANYTHING ELSE HERE])
```

is that going to be always true?  I say yes, because it contains (D OR (NOT D)), which is always true no matter what.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is correct, by the reason you mentioned.

**EDIT:** In more detail, since disjunction is associative, you end with something of the form $T\vee P$, with $T$ true and $P$ your "anything else".

Answer (score 0):

At propositional logic this is called "Excluded Middle". Note that you also have a "Contradiction". That is when:

```
D AND (NOT D)
```

It looks alike, but this is always false. You can test this with a truth table.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! This does not really provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have [sufficient reputation](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can [comment on any post](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).